# What is the logic behind these two programs?

Tags: php

I have a program to reverse a number, which is as follow:

```
<?php
function reverse_num($num){
    $sum = 0;
    while(floor($num)){
        $newnum = $num % 10;
        $sum = $sum * 10 + $newnum;
        $num = $num / 10;
    }
        return $sum;
}

echo reverse_num(89);
?>
```

I tried to test this in different condition, like I return the $sum inside the loop. Like,

```
<?php
function reverse_num($num){
    $sum = 0;
    while(floor($num)){
        $newnum = $num % 10;
        $sum = $sum * 10 + $newnum;
        $num = $num / 10;
        return $sum;
    }
}

echo reverse_num(89);
?>
```

I am unable to understand why does not it reverse the number. It is returning 9 as answer. But in my opinion it should be 8, beacuse when loop will run for second time with value of 8, it should return 8 as answer. Also why it does not return the reverse of the number?

Comment: You have invented the wheel. Everyone else uses this http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrev.php

Comment: return ends execution of your function immediately. The loop will only execute one time.

Comment: No, it's not like that. I am doing these for learning purpose. I agree with your point that we should follow standard function. But I am here clearing the doubts.

Comment: Ohhh! Thank you @Don'tPanic. I was not aware of this concept.

Comment: You're welcome. There's a wealth of knowledge on it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php).